# Other methods do not work correctly within the event handler. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, event-handling

My problem is that the event handler method is called even when the event itself was not called by the publisher.

```
private Queue<Command> _commands = new(1000);

private Timer _timer = new(10000);

private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(_commands.Count);

    _timer.Elapsed += OnReload;
}

private void OnReload(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _commands.Dequeue();
}

private void Awake()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        _commands.Enqueue(new FightingCommand());
    }
}
```

[image: Don't Worked (Debug log)]

But I found a solution to this: do not call another (necessary for me) method in the event handler method, but create a variable of type Boolean and assign some value and then work with this variable. PLEASE CAN SOMEONE EXPLAIN WHY AND HOW TO DO THE SAME WITHOUT CREATING A NEW VARIABLE! Thanks.

```
private Queue<Command> _commands = new(1000);

private Timer _timer = new(10000);

private bool _isEnd;

private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(_commands.Count);

    _timer.Elapsed += OnReload;

    if (_isEnd)
    {
        _commands.Dequeue();

        _isEnd = false;
    }
}

private void OnReload(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //_commands.Dequeue();

    _isEnd = true;
}

private void Awake()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        _commands.Enqueue(new FightingCommand());
    }
}
```

[image: Worked (Debug log)]

Comment: Dequeue might throw an exception if there are no more items

Comment: Please I would avice you to fill the **_commands** with _commands.Enqueue in the **Start()** function not in the **Awake()**

Comment: @KlausGütter The problem is that all items are deleted in a second. Look at the attached image and the deletion period

Comment: @thunderkill The fact is that in the original program, _commands elements are added remotely. In addition, in any case, all elements are added successfully. The event handler is called even when it is not called in the event publisher class, although it works fine with variables and fields

Comment: I don't know Unity well, but do you also unsubscribe from the Elapsed event somewhere?

Comment: @KlausGütter No.

Comment: @KlausGütter Perhaps you mean that if an event is subscribed to several times, then when the event itself is called by the publisher, the event handler will be called several times?

Comment: Yes, this is the case

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@KlausGütter**, I only needed to register an event once and this event will call the subscriber method (before I thought that only when an event is signed the subscriber method of the event handler is called).